# Showing a list of roles from a user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've searched the entire internet and can't find the answer why my code isn't working

```
const user = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.member.user
const member = guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
//------------------------------------------------------
user.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | ')
```

And error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

`user.roles` has to be changed to `user.roles.cache` in this case.

`user.roles` in this case returns an instance of a [GuildMemberRoleManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache), which is not able to be mapped.
`user.roles.cache` is the correct line in this case, since it returns a collection, which can be mapped.

```
const user = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.member.user
const member = guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
//------------------------------------------------------
user.roles.cache.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | ')
```

Comment: I have now `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`

Comment: sorry about that, i made another major mistake. user should be replaced with member.